# Joining two table and including all rows even with out matches

Tags: mysql

Looking for away to join 2 tables and keeping all records from the left. The problem is that one of the on statement does not exist in the the other table

Example

> Table1 ID, ClassID, Date, Amount
>
> Table2 ID, CLassID, Date, Score

Example statement

```
select 
   Table1.ID, 
   Table1.ClassID, 
   Table1.Date, 
   Table1.Amount, 
   Table2.Score
from Table1
 left join Table2 on Table2.ID = Table1.ID 
      and Table2.ClassID = Table1.ClassID 
      and Table2.Date = Table1.Date
```

The Problem is Table1 has an ClassID that Table2 does not have and it is excluding that from the results. If I removed the ClassID as a qualification, I get a ton of duplicates

Comment: Use `select coalesce(Table1.ClassID, Table2.ClassID)`

Comment: Is `table1.classId` required?

Comment: What is the PK FK constraint between the two tables? Wouldn't just ID or ClassID be sufficient?

Comment: Yes the classid is required.

Comment: Did you try the code below to see if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing value will be null for Score so you will have to deal with that however you like, but this will do the job.

```
select 
   Table1.ID, 
   Table1.ClassID, 
   Table1.Date, 
   Table1.Amount, 
   ( SELECT Score 
     FROM Table2 
     WHERE ID = Table1.ID 
     and ClassID = Table1.ClassID 
     and Date = Table1.Date ) AS 'Score'
from Table1
```